# I/O Error 32 in gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

I am trying to use Gamemaker Studio 1.4 on my Lenovo but every time I open it I get:

```
I/O Error 32
```

This used to just happen when I tried to close the program but now I can't even open a project or do anything because I get multiple error notifications filling my screen. I have tried the following but none work:

> Rebooting my device
>   
> Deleting and downloading Gamemaker
>   
> Closing all my programs and files and then trying to open

Is there a bug?

If not how can I fix this?

I can't update gamemaker either as it can't close

Comment: Please people, im doing a project and need gamemaker

Comment: What version of gamemaker??

Comment: Is it a 32 bit error or maybe you have a cracked version, those tend to have errors

Comment: @Daedric Gamemaker Studio, not proffesional

Comment: Its Gamemaker studio 1.4

Comment: Studios is buggy, I get issues too. http://steamcommunity.com/app/214850/discussions/0/540736781125926380/ this might help its out of memory :(

Answer (score 0):

Best place to ask is the yoyo games forums

http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=605158

Here is your issue, seems to have multiple fixes that may or may not work, seems to vary.

Answer (score 0):

**I DID IT!!!!!**

THANKS @Daedric!

Okay, so I saw something that said use task manager. So when it was updating I closed down the studio using task manager, and then when it relaunched its fine!